# Rails calling a task in lib/tasks folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a backup.rake file in the lib/tasks folder

task looks like this:

```
require 'find'
namespace :backup do  
  desc "Backup the database to a file." 
  task :mysqldump => [:environment] do
  end
end
```

Now I want to call this from a controller like this:

```
system "RAILS_ENV="+Rails.env+"rake backup:mysqldump"
```

But I got this error:

```
sh: 1: backup:mysqldump: not found
```

What is the problem? I do exactly the same with other tasks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this

```
system "RAILS_ENV="+Rails.env+" rake backup:mysqldump"
```

a space between `" rake`

Answer (score 1):

In controller you can use like this:

```
def method
  %x[rake rake backup:mysqldump]
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke(args)
```